# Why does LINQ-to-SQL not create singular class for table named "ApplicationMenus"?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When I generate LINQ-to-SQL classes for a table named **ApplicationMenus** it doesn't create a **singular** class for it so that the statement:

```
ApplicationMenu applicationMenu = new ApplicationMenu();
```

gives an error.

If I **change the name** of the table to one of these:

```
Menus
ApplicationMenuItems
```

then it correctly generates the singular class.

**Why does LINQ-to-SQL have a problem with "ApplicationMenus" and what other names will cause a problem as well?**

[image]

Comment: Related but different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794872/linq-to-sql-with-table-name-ending-in-es-creates-wrong-entity-class-name

Comment: I can understand it might have a problem with difficult words such as "Campuses" etc. (although a simple little mapping table would take care of that), but the odd thing is that it works with "Menus" but not "ApplicationMenus".

Comment: Are you not able to change the generated class name in the properties of the linq-to-sql file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflector to find out, or you could ask yourself why you have pluralized table names ;-)

Comment: Perhaps because he has a "table of application menus"? instead of "table of application menu"? It's like "public List<Employee> Employee { get; set; }" in C#, it just gives you the wrong impression. Is it 1 employee or a list of employees, or what? Of course, if the "application menu" is a list of items, so that the table actually contains items instead of multiple menus, then the naming is just odd.