# Why are tables pluralised in linq-to-sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

All the table names are appended with a 's'?

Like table test will appear as tests in the coding.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a bug, its a feature of LinqToSql called pluralization - you can disable it by reading the following Stackoverflow topic:

[Linq to SQL: How do I stop the auto generated object name from being renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335792/linq-to-sql-how-do-i-stop-the-auto-generated-object-name-from-being-renamed)