# Linq-to-sql dbml generator is not adding "s" for table properties of context

Tags: linq-to-sql

When I delete and load again an entity, i found many errors in code, looks like DataContext wrap for GetTable changed own name. For example I had name: i9 and table property was i9s. Now its "i9". What option do this? And how to get back?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/335804/1266461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an option in settings -> database (attention: can be hided by checkbox below) -> o/r designer -> plural = yes

Comment: Couldn't get these settings. Can you please provide some steps?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) (i.e, command line tool) to generate the classes? In SqlMetal add the `/pluralize` option. If you're using the LINQ to SQL designer it should do this by default.