# Disabling automatic pluralization in Linq to SQL Classes for a single class only

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have a single table name with an irregular plural (the plural is the same as the singular). Is there any way to disable the automatic pluralization (Account = DB.Accounts) for that single table while retaining the feature for the others?

Answer (score 21):

You need to disable the Pluralize Table Names for the LINQ to SQL designer.

To do this navigate to Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> O/R Designer and change the Pluralization of names to false.

Then you will need to recompile your project and it should address the naming

[Linq to SQL: How do I stop the auto generated object name from being renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335792/linq-to-sql-how-do-i-stop-the-auto-generated-object-name-from-being-renamed)

Comment: I've changed this setting in VS, but recompiling doesn't get rid of the pluralization. I can manually change the class names to remove pluralization. But I've noticed if I make changes to the .dbml and save, it'll change the designer.cs outside of source control, and add back pluralization...

Comment: What I had to do was remove and replace all the tables in my .dbml, save, and the pluralization setting took affect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really only worried about a single class, I would let the Framework pluralize the name and then simply manually remove the pluralization for the one class you're worried about.

Comment: After every change to the .dbml file you need to repeat the process as it is auto-generated. I tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can´t do this using pure Linq2SQL.

On Entity Frameowrk + T4 template for generate Linq 2 SQL entities you can customize a T4 template for take control of pluralization, implementing your own rules exceptions.