# LINQ to SQL DBML: Drag and Drop changing table names

Tags: wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

Currently we are manually updating the DBML by deleting all tables and then re-adding all of them again through Server Explorer. We have had no problems doing it this way before. Recently  after deleting and then re-adding all of the tables, one or two of the tables will have changed their names having us to go back and fix either the DBML or the LINQ objects in the code behind.

For example lets say we have a table called TABLES_MINORS. Conventionally it should be named TABLES_MINORs. But sometimes it comes out as TABLEs_MINORs, TABLEs_MINORS, or TABLES_MINORS. This is getting quite annoying and I have no clue why its doing it. Again this does not happen every time and when it does happen it only affects one or two tables.

Comment: Thanks @Nate, that last part threw me off a bit.  Glad you cleaned up for us.

Comment: @Paxenos No problem. Happy to be of service.

Comment: @jes9582 Do you have multiple versions of VS (i.e. English, German, etc) doing this? or is this behavior observed solely from your dev machine?

Comment: @jes9582 You may want to check out dmbltools. I've never used it, but read good things -- http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Comment: @Nate yea we were using SQLMetal and it worked out ok but it became to much of a hassle and caused us more problems in the long run. this problem isnt a HUGE deal i just wanted to see if anyone else has experienced this same thing.

Comment: @jes9582 Wish I could say I have. I have never been fully happy with the pluralization tool, so I've always just done it manually. I have not had to deal with too many large graphs so it wasn't much of an issue to redo it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: In VS, open Tools --> Options --> O/R Designer, set Pluralization of names to false.

Similar to questions:

[Disabling automatic pluralization in Linq to SQL Classes for a single class only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245105/disabling-automatic-pluralization-in-linq-to-sql-classes-for-a-single-class-only)

[Linq to SQL: How do I stop the auto generated object name from being renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335792/linq-to-sql-how-do-i-stop-the-auto-generated-object-name-from-being-renamed)