# Visual Studio dropping 's' off of sql server tables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

When adding in tables from SQL Server to a dbml, it will drop the 's' off of the table name. One example: when adding the table 'Alias' it will change the name to 'Alia'. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Method of adding tables: 
  1) Connect to database in the Server Explorer Tab 
  2) Open tables folder
  3) Select all the tables and drag them to the open dbml window

Comment: What mechanism are you using to add tables?

Comment: @Gabe updated to include method of adding tables

Comment: Oh, I see. This is an issue of the "s" not being displayed when using the tables in a certain viewer. It thinks the table name is plural and is trying to make it singular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using entity framework, and adding tables via the update wizard, there is a checkbox which says "Pluralize or singularize generated object names":

[image: update wizard]

You can uncheck that and it will leave your table names alone.

**Update**: looks like you are drag/dropping to DBML, try this link:

[Linq to SQL: How do I stop the auto generated object name from being renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335792/linq-to-sql-how-do-i-stop-the-auto-generated-object-name-from-being-renamed)

Comment: Okay that's what is going on. I didn't know exactly what to search for.